# Serving Flash SWF from a Document Library?

Tags: document-library

I've created a custom Web Part dedicated to displaying swf content. It uses swfobject and jquery to serve and display the flash file.

If the SWF is placed in a Document Library (/Documents/test.swf), the flash file will not load. It appears that the size (width and height) is detected, but the flash file doesn't load or play.

Alternatively, if the SWF is served from the file system (/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/FlashTest/test.swf) OR from an external site the flash serves, displays, loads and plays just fine.

I have turned on Permissive Browser File Handling for the Web Application with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing off the top of my head that would prevent it from loading, assuming the user has the appropriate permissions to the library. You mentioned that you're using swfobject to load it, which I've had a lot of success with in SP2010.

You might try putting the SWF in the Style Library or some other location within the site to try and pin it down, it sounds like permissions to me. The size is specified in the swfobject call, so it's not necessarily getting the size from the SWF itself, but rather from the swfobject call; which just means it's writing the object tags, not necessarily accessing the SWF.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to handle "Browser File Handle" issue. Take a look at my blog here: http://www.pdfsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-and-pdf-integration-series-part-1/

Solution #2 addresses Pdf extension without exposing entire Web Application to "Permissive" browsing. Setting "Browsing File Handle" to "permissive" opens too many vulnerabilities with other file extensions.

Thanks,

Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your web part is created, but it appears that someone else tried to do the same thing with some success.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/MOSSFlashWebPart.aspx

Take a look, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Sharepoint 2010 is blocking the ability to open HTML (swf) documents directly from a document library.

However this can be changed by adjusting the browser file handling option. The option is located here:

1. Central Admin\Application Management\Manage Web Applications.
2. Select General Settings for the specified web application
3. For Browser file handling, select permissive. The default is strict​

I have found answer here:
http://paritala-sasi.blogspot.com/2009/12/opening-html-files-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Sorry szpilla, but in my original question I explicitly said that I had already done this. This isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes flash content does not work in SharePoint 2010 because flash files are not enabled by default. To solve this problem, here is a solution – http://tech-turf.blogspot.com/2015/10/making-flash-content-swf-files-work-in.html

Comment: Link only answers are not very helpful. Its possible that links get broken. So for future readers if you can please extract some important information from the blog you have specified, would be very helpful.